# How to Bar Chart (with Dates on x-axis) after Groupby operation

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have a large df where I have used a group operation on "topic_nmf" and "dates" and counted occurrences of topic_nmf

sample DF

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'topic_nmf':[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2], 'date':['2020-08','2020-06','2020-05','2020-02','2019-11','2019-08','2020-03','2020-02', '2019-10','2019-09'], 'count':[3,5,3,5,6,3,3,9,2,1]})
```

[image: Output]

The real df is much larger (it has 40 top_nmf)

I wish to do either a line plot, or a bar chart with the 'date'(year/month) on the x-axes
and the 'count' on the y-axis.

Each 'topic_nmf' is in itself a trendline, or color coded bar on the bar chart.

My attempt is as follows:

```
plt.bar(df3.date, df3.count)
```

but I get the following error:

*TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'method'*

Any help appreciated.

Update: Thanks that does help, although i am not quite there

```
df3.set_index('date').plot.bar()

df3.set_index('date').plot()
```

[image: as suggested, gives]

However,I am seeking three trendlines (each labelled 0,1,2) and same for bar chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `date` as index. By default, index is plotted on the `x axis`.

```
df3.set_index('date').plot.bar()

df3.set_index('date').plot()
```

Following your comments. Please try

```
df3.groupby(['date','topic_nmf'])['count'].sum().unstack().plot.bar()
#df3.groupby(['date','topic_nmf'])['count'].sum().unstack().plot()#lineplot
```

[image]

Comment: thanks @wwnde, that is helpful. But I don't quite get there. Apologies, my initial question should have been made clearer

Comment: @Prolle See my edits and let me know if you need further help

Comment: many thanks and I am sorry for not upvoting. Thanks again for unlocking this one for me. Stay safe